# Hibernate OGM on Wildfly not storing entities

Tags: java, mongodb, wildfly-10, hibernate-ogm

I am trying to store an entity using Hibernate OGM 5.1 on Wildfly 10.1 with MongoDb. Nothing is being stored.

When the persistence code runs, it gets no exceptions. There are no warnings or exceptions in the Wildfly logs. The logs indicate a successful connection to the mongodb server has been made and the log statements in the persistence code report that the session was saved. The mongodb logs report no errors. However, nothing is saved in the authentication database. The Sessions collection does not exist.

My persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence 
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="mongo-ogm-auth">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ogm.jpa.HibernateOgmPersistence</provider>
    <class>org.secomm.authenticator.persistence.ServerVault</class>
    <class>org.secomm.authenticator.persistence.Sessions</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.database" value="authentication"/>
      <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.host" value="xxxx"/>
      <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.provider" value="mongodb"/>
      <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.username" value="xxxx" />
      <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.password" value="xxxx"/>
      <property name="hibernate.ogm.mongodb.authentication_database" value="authentication"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

My entity:

```
@Entity
public class Sessions {

    /**
     * 
     */
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private ObjectId id;

    /**
     * 
     */
    private int sessionId;

    /**
     * 
     */
    private long authToken;

    /**
     * 
     */
    private long timestamp;

    /* Getters and setters */

}
```

My persistence code:

```
/**
 * 
 */
@PersistenceUnit(name="mongo-ogm-auth")
private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

private void storeSession(SessionContext context) {

    try {
        logger.trace("Storing the session info");
        EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

        Sessions session = new Sessions();
        session.setSessionId(context.getSessionId());
        session.setAuthToken(0);
        session.setTimestamp(System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);

        entityManager.persist(session);
        entityManager.close();
        logger.trace("Session info stored");
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        logger.warn("Unknown exception - " + e.getClass().getName() + " - " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }

}
```

Comment: Is the code inside a transaction? Even if MongoDB is not transactional, Hibernate OGM is supposed will use transaction demarcation to group the operations.

Comment: Originally, I got an error when trying to use the EntityManager transaction. Using the Arjuna transaction manager works, though. The documentation says that managed transactions are preferred, but it does not say they are required. In any case, thank you for the help.